# PHP Distinct Equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I know that if you can use distinct in an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;
```

In order to pull all the unique matching data so it is not replicated over and over again in a loop. I am having a bit of a conundrum in which I have a SELECT statement using Joins; everything is working great. From that loop that I have created there is an IF and Else statement. If the data falls between a certain date range then the relevant data is displayed. However if it does not fall in the date range then I just want some of the data displayed.

The problem is that the else statement is intent on replicating the data for each time that data is repeated in each row in the database. Now I really dont want to use two separate queries so I am seeing if anyone has had any experience with this in the past and what they did to get around it.

For those of you who dont understand what I'm getting at I'll include the code:

```
    // Database query
    $db_query = mysqli_query($con,$db_data_query);
while($db_result = mysqli_fetch_array($db_query)) {

     // Convert to proper datetime format
    $dt_vdate = new DateTime($view_date);
    $convert_vdate = $dt_vdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Check if the date is within the date range
    if (( $convert_vdate >= $db_result['start'] ) && ( $convert_vdate <= $db_result['finish'] )) {

    // Display Jobs within Range
    echo '
    <div class="db_col">
        <div class="person">'.  $db_result['name'] . ' #' . $db_result['id'] .'</div>
        <div class="location">'. $db_result['location'] .'</div>
        <div class="task">' . $db_result['task'] . '</div>
    </div>';
    }
    // Display blank tasks
    else if (**( $db_result['start'] == "" ) && ( $db_result['finish'] == "" )**){

        // Display Jobs within Range
    echo '
    <div class="db_col">
        <div class="person">'.  $db_result['name'] . ' #' . $db_result['id'] .'</div>
        <div class="location">'. $db_result['location'] .'</div>
        <div class="task">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>';        
    }
```

I put ** beside the elseif conditions. I have a funny feeling I will need to break this into two queries but to make life easy I was thinking if there was anyway to basically check if the person has an assigned task inbetween the date ranges, then display the person's name, id # and assigned task. If they dont have a task assigned then instead (using the else if) just display their name, id #, and a blank div.

This way this page can be printed off, and tasks can be manually written on the pages that can later be written in by hand.

The problem in what is happening is the database is displaying the assigned people and tasks fine. But if they are not assigned a task, then for each time they were assigned a task in the past then the person and their ID # and the blank div are being displayed for each one of those database entries. So I'm trying to brainstorm a way that if the person isn't assigned a task, then the else if displays the person, id, task once (not multiple times).

Comment: I'm assuming that your select distinct isn't doing what you want because the 'task' column differs each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given my comment above is correct, you can do a workaround by storing the person's 'id' value in an array and checking using in_array:

```
:
:
$got_ids=array();
while (...)
{
  $testid=$db_result['id'];
  if (in_array($testid,$got_ids)) continue;
  :
  :
  $got_ids[]=$testid;
} // end while
```

should solve the problem

Comment: I'll give that a shot shortly, just tied up with something quick. But yes your comment was correct about the task constantly changing. Which is why this becomes so difficult for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: Ok it works...sorta so now it is displaying everything perfectly *BUT* it isn't showing any of the newly generated tasks like it should. I'm going to keep fiddling with it.

Comment: Try putting the if(in_array(... inside your else if clause.

Comment: Ok I found a problem, not sure if you'll see this but this modification you gave me worked great at displaying the names and ids exactly like I wanted. However when a task is assigned to an individual it is displaying the same name and ID twice (once with the task and once blank with the blank entry). I tried to limit it using the else if so it only begins the loop with the blank entries if there is no task but had no luck. I tried to detect which $db_result['task']'s had content, then eliminating those out of the array using array_diff &/or unset again no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: OK - here's an idea: try using coalesce function to convert a null start to some fixed early date then sort by start desc. That way you will hit all the assigned tasks first. Then if the if(in_array... is at the start of then else if( it will never pick up an unassigned task if any assigned exist for the person. You should also get all the assigned tasks for eac person.